# Debug in ColdFusion 8 using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a problem when configuring debug in ColdFusion version 8. I followed this guide to setup my eclipse http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/debugger.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader

But I could not find RDS configuration, although I added a new RDS user in ColdFusion server.

Who has experience in this problem?

Comment: Did you enable RDS when you installed ColdFusion?

Comment: when setting up Cold Fusion version 8, I already enabled RDS and input username and password. But It still doesn't work.

Comment: _"But I could not find RDS configuration"_ - what does that mean? Are you getting an error?  If so, what is the error. Did you successfully install the `CF8-Extensions-for-Eclipse.zip`?

Comment: I installed successfully CF8-Extensions-for-Eclipse.zip inside Eclipse (Juno version), I already enabled RDS and input username and password when setting up Cold Fusion version 8. But when I check in Eclipse : window > References > Cold Fusion. I didn't see RDS Configuration. Thank you too much.

Comment: In the Window > Preferences dialog window, on the left-side at the top there is an input box with the text "type filter text" in it. Click in that box and type `RDS`. That should display the RDS option(s) for you.